# Is it possible to featurize C# collections using ML.NET Preview (0.6)?

Tags: c#, collections, ml.net

Lets say I have a complex type of:

```
class Policy
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    DateTime InceptionDate { get; set; }
    DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

class Location
{
    string Street { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
    string State { get; set; }
    string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

How can I convert the collection of `Locations` into a featurized column for ML.NET to understand?

Comment: I may not be asking this question correctly. I'm trying to relate complex object relationships (having collections) to actual data files (csv, json, etc.) that will be use to train a model.

Comment: I believe I am looking for an equivalent of `Microsoft.ML.Legacy.Data.CollectionDataSource.Create` using the new API. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If your class not a flat list of properties, you cannot read a collection of these objects into an `IDataView`, and never could. You need to perform the pre-processing, then feed the tabular data to `IDataView`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to featurize an **Array** of **primitive** types.

If your class looked like this:

```
class Policy
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    DateTime InceptionDate { get; set; }
    DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    float[] Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Then `Locations` would translate to a `Vector` of type `R4` (mapping for `float`).

Then you create a `SchemaDefinition`:

```
var env = new LocalEnvironment();
var schemaDef = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(Policy));
```

If the Vector's size is unknown in compile time you would also need:

```
int vectorSize = 4
schemaDef["Locations"].ColumnType = new VectorType(NumberType.R4, vectorSize);
```

If the Vector's size is fixed you can add the `VectorType` attribute on the property:

```
class Policy
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    DateTime InceptionDate { get; set; }
    DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [VectorType(4)]
    float[] Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create the `DataView`:

```
var data = new List<Policy>();
var dataView = env.CreateStreamingDataView(data, schemaDef);
```

In your case, `Locations` is a class, so I believe you would first need to convert this to a primitive array by concatenating the values like in this example:

```
public class IrisData
{
    public float Label;
    public float SepalLength;
    public float SepalWidth;
    public float PetalLength;
    public float PetalWidth;
}

public class IrisVectorData
{
    public float Label;
    public float[] Features;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Here's a data array that we want to work on.
    var dataArray = new[] {
        new IrisData{Label=1, PetalLength=1, SepalLength=1, PetalWidth=1, SepalWidth=1},
        new IrisData{Label=0, PetalLength=2, SepalLength=2, PetalWidth=2, SepalWidth=2}
    };

    // Create the ML.NET environment.
    var env = new Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.TlcEnvironment();

    // Create the data view.
    // This method will use the definition of IrisData to understand what columns there are in the 
    // data view.
    var dv = env.CreateDataView<IrisData>(dataArray);

    // Now let's do something to the data view. For example, concatenate all four non-label columns
    // into 'Features' column.
    dv = new Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data.ConcatTransform(env, dv, "Features", 
        "SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth");

    // Read the data into an another array, this time we read the 'Features' and 'Label' columns
    // of the data, and ignore the rest.
    // This method will use the definition of IrisVectorData to understand which columns and of which types
    // are expected to be present in the input data.
    var arr = dv.AsEnumerable<IrisVectorData>(env, reuseRowObject: false)
        .ToArray();
}
```

But I haven't really tried this case yet so I can't help more here.

Also check the Schema Comprehension documentation [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/SchemaComprehension.md)

Answer (score 2):

An example that reads data from memory into an ML pipeline with the new APIs can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/MlNetCookBook.md#what-if-my-training-data-is-not-in-a-text-file). Copying the relevant code, although the link has some additional helpful comments:

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();

IEnumerable<CustomerChurnInfo> churnData = GetChurnInfo();

var trainData = mlContext.CreateStreamingDataView(churnData);

var dynamicLearningPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("DemographicCategory")
    .Append(new ConcatEstimator(mlContext, "Features", "DemographicCategory", "LastVisits"))
    .Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree("HasChurned", "Features", numTrees: 20));

var dynamicModel = dynamicLearningPipeline.Fit(trainData);
```